# Button not calling a function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am creating a simple array counter and sorter for school and have encountered a problem with the Count button calling the count() function. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script language=javascript>
      var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Keyboard","Headset"];


      function sort() {
        products.toString()
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Unsorted array = " + products;
        products.sort();
        products.toString();
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Sorted array = " + products;
      }

      function count() {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "The amount of items in the array is: " + fruit.length;
      }
    </script>
    <title>Task 2</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" name="butt1" value="Sort!" onclick="sort()"/>
    <input type="button" name="butt2" value="Count!" onclick="count()"/>



    <p id="result"></p>
    <p id="result2"></p>
    <p id="count"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fruit` doesn't exist in your source code so where is it defined.... Use your browsers console for debugging and checking error reports.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `fruit` is not visible to the count function

I guess you want to use the `products` here

```
function count() {
     document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "The amount of items in the array is: " + products.length;
}
```

Or if you want to use `fruit`, then you need to declare and initialize it globally

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a silly overlook.

Comment: @KaiyaMiller and check your products variable, it has '`enter code here`'. Please delete that.

Comment: I don't see ' enter code here ' in the products variable.

Comment: @KaiyaMiller it was a mistake when you post code in so textarea .

Comment: Aha, okay. I'll keep that in mind next time.